# AG Grid Enterprise React: hide all root group items expand/collapse controll

Tags: typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have AgGridReact Enterprise with Typescript and I'm using it to create a tree.

[My Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szm2U.png)

I want to know how to hide controls for only root (those at level 0) group items/nodes (items with red mark: A1, G13, G56h).
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to hide expand/collapse feature for root levels. Use cellRendererSelector like that.

```
const autoGroupColumnDef = useMemo(() => {
  return {
    minWidth: 200,
    cellRendererSelector: (params) => {
      if (params.node.field == "root") {
        return
      }
      else 
        return {
          component: 'agGroupCellRenderer'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, [])

return (
  <AgGridReact
    autoGroupColumnDef={autoGroupColumnDef}
    groupDefaultExpanded={2}
  ></AgGridReact>
)
```

Fully working plunker: https://plnkr.co/plunk/p84rlFMVWM64r6zI